# How can i get messages randomly from multiple Queue's

Tags: java

I have multiple Queue's(created by using activemq).I want to get a message's from Queue's randomly
is it possible?
If possible please tell me...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen to multiple queues, you can listen to multiple queues in the same session and you will get a callback for one event at a time from multiple queues.